# Vector question relating to triangle $ABC$

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, triangles

> Two altitudes of a triangle $ABC$ meet at $H$, as shown. Relative to some origin $O$ the position vectors of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $H$ are $a$,$b$,$c$ and $h$. Show that
> $$
> (h-a)\cdot(b-c)=(h-b)\cdot(c-a)=0
> $$
> Deduce that $(h-c)\cdot(b-a)=0$ and hence that the three altitudes of a triangle are concurrent.

[image: Picture of the triangle]

I tried expanding the brackets but it confused me and I couldn't get anything meaningful from it, I also tried substituting different vectors to get to the same vector position but I couldn't derive anything meaningful. I also tried putting them as a dot product as shown below:

$$
(h-a).(b-c)=\sqrt{(h-a)^2(b-c)^2}\cos(x)
$$
$$
\cos(x)=1
$$
$$
x=0°
$$

However, that means they are parallel which is not the case or they wouldn't equal $0$.

Anymore advice you could give me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the distributive property render

$(h-a)\cdot(b-c)=h\cdot b-a\cdot b -h\cdot c+a\cdot c$.

Do the same for

$(h-b)\cdot(c-a)=...$

$(h-c)\cdot(a-b)=...$

And add them up.

$(h-a)\cdot(b-c)+(h-b)\cdot(c-a)+(h-c)\cdot(a-b)=...$ (hint:  you might find yourself canceling terms.)

Thereby if two of the terms in the sum are zero, then the third term is ... .

Comment: So will it be $0$ too because when you add $(h-a).(b-c)$ and $(h-b).(c-a)$, they are exactly the same as when you multiply out $(h-c).(a-b)$ I think?

Comment: Hit the bull's eye.